# RichEditBox crashes in certain condition.

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

Rich edit box crashes for me if I try to set the fontsize to it.

C# code:

```
REB_Value.Document.SetText(TextSetOptions.None, "Company  Name,  \nStreet name with zip code. \n123-456-7890");
```

The XAML:

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
       <TextBlock Text="Lable for this Field:" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"/>
       <RichEditBox Name="REB_Value"            
                    ContextMenuOpening="OnContextMenuOpening" 
                    Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}" 
                    SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged" >
      </RichEditBox> 
 </StackPanel>
```

Style:

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="RichEditBox">
        ...
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource TextControlBorderThemeThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
       ...
    </Style>
```

The page renders/Loads if I remove the property `<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>`  or If I put an /n at the end of my string
 ie: `"Company  Name,  \nStreet name with zip code. \n123-456-7890\n"`

There are other RichEditBoxes which works fine,
eg:

```
SomeOtherREB.Document.SetText(TextSetOptions.None, "123456789");
```

I don't understand why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show the crash stack?  I tried to create a repro but couldn't hit the issue.  Let me know what I need to change to hit the crash:
https://github.com/finnigantime/Samples/tree/master/examples/Win8Xaml/REBCrash

Comment: For some reason, I'm not able to reproduce it now. It works without the "\n" now. :? Weird.